# All combinations from aaa to ~~~

Tags: javascript

I have this code that works fine until "zzz". I would like to change it minimun possible to include special chars on it:

```js
    var str= 'aaa',
    s= str;
    
    while(str!=='zzz') {
      str= ((parseInt(str, 36)+1).toString(36)).replace(/0/g,'a');
      s+= '<br/> '+str;
    }
    
    document.body.innerHTML= s;
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/f75xe0nb/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not go with your code as it looks like any 'minimum' modification to it might end up with infinite loop.

So instead I offer you a different approach under this fiddle. It requires defining the scope of used characters, so you can include the whole alphabet and then the special chars required.

https://jsfiddle.net/v4r1wdrd

```
var chars = "abcde$%^";

var s = '';
for(var i=0; i<chars.length; i++)
    for(var j=0; j<chars.length; j++)
        for(var k=0; k<chars.length; k++)
           s += chars[i]+chars[j]+chars[k] + '<br>';

document.body.innerHTML = s;
```

Comment: Yep. I completely agree. It's better to use a lookup table (even if it's just a string) for something like this. We're not coding in C so don't make it look like C code.

Comment: Thank you, yehh i think it's better this way.